# How to vectorize multiple levels of recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, numpy, vectorization

I am a noobie to python and numpy (and programming in general). I am trying to speed up my code as much as possible. The math involves several summations over multiple axes of a few arrays. I've attained one level of vectorization, but I can't seem to get any deeper than that and have to resort to for loops (I believe there's three levels of recursion, M, N, and I, one of which I've eliminated, I).  Here's my code for the relevant section (this code works, but I'd like to speed it up):

```
def B1(n, i):
    return np.pi * n * dmaxi * (-1)**(n+1) * np.sin(qi[i]*dmaxi) * ((np.pi*n)**2 - (qi[i]*dmaxi)**2)**(-1)

for n in N:
    B[n, :] = B1(n, I)

for m in M:
    for n in N:
        C[m, n] = np.dot((1/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]))*B[m, :], B[n, :])

    Y[m] = np.dot((1/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]))*U[0, :, 1], B[m, :])

A = np.linalg.solve(C[1:, 1:], (0.25)*Y[1:])
```

dmaxi is just a float and m, n and i are integers.  The arrays have the following shapes:

```
>>> qi.shape
(551,)
>>> N.shape
(18,)
>>> M.shape
(18,)
>>> I.shape
(551,)
>>> Iq.shape
(1, 551, 3)
>>> U.shape
(1, 551, 3)
```

As you can see I've vectorized the calculation of the 2nd axis of B, but I can't seem to do it for the 1st axis, C, and Y, which still require the for loops.  It seems that when I try to do the same form of vectorization that I did for the 1st axis of B (define a function, then give the array as the argument), I get a broadcasting error since it appears to be trying to calculate both axes simultaneously, rather than the 1st, then the 2nd, which is why I had to force it into a for loop instead.  The same problem occurs for both C and Y which is why they're both in for loops also.  In case that's confusing, essentially what I tried was:

```
>>> B[:, :] = B1(N, I)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sasrec_v6.py", line 155, in B1
    return np.pi * n * dmaxi * (-1)**(n+1) * np.sin(qi[i]*dmaxi) * ((np.pi*n)**2 - (qi[i]*dmaxi)**2)**(-1)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18) (551)
```

Vectorizing the 2nd axis of B made a substantial improvement to the speed of my code, so I'm assuming that the same will apply for further vectorization (I hope I'm using that term correctly by the way).

Comment: The code you provided does not appear to use recursion at all.

Comment: I may be using the term incorrectly.  I'm simply referring to the use of the nested for loops.

Comment: So, lowercase `i` is not an integer but a vector,  the same as uppercase `i`?

Comment: @moarningsun I think `i` is the parameter name, `I` will be the argument in its place.

Comment: What are the expected shapes of `B`, `C`, and `Y`. I thought I had it figured out but I think I'm making a mistake.

Comment: I = np.arange(x) where x is the number of elements.  I just made it to simplify the notation for myself.

Comment: B.shape should equal (len(N), len(I)), C.shape = (len(N), len(N)), and Y.shape = (len(N))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to make 2d arrays from your 1d index vectors.  I haven't tested these yet, but they should work:

If you reshape the `N` to be a column vector, then `B1` will return a 2d array:

```
B[N] = B1(N[:, None], I)
```

For `Y` and `C`, I'd use `np.einsum` to have better control over which axes are mulitplied (probably this could be done with `np.dot` as well but I'm not sure how.

```
C[M[:, None], N] = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',
        B[M]/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]),
        B[N])

Y[M] = np.einsum('i, ki->k',
        U[0, :, 1]/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]),
        B[M])
```

To see what that indexing trick does:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(3)

In [2]: a
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [3]: a[:, None]
Out[3]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [4]: b = np.arange(4,1,-1)

In [5]: b
Out[5]: array([4, 3, 2])

In [6]: a[:, None] * b
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [4, 3, 2],
       [8, 6, 4]])
```

It saves two orders of magnitude in time:

```
In [92]: %%timeit
   ....: B = np.zeros((18, 551))
   ....: C = np.zeros((18, 18))
   ....: Y = np.zeros((18))
   ....: for n in N:
   ....:     B[n, :] = B1(n, I)
   ....: for m in M:
   ....:     for n in N:
   ....:         C[m, n] = np.dot((1/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]))*B[m, :], B[n, :])
   ....:     Y[m] = np.dot((1/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]))*U[0, :, 1], B[m, :])
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [93]: %%timeit
   ....: Bv = np.zeros((18, 551))
   ....: Cv = np.zeros((18, 18))
   ....: Yv = np.zeros((18))
   ....: Bv[N] = B1(N[:, None], I)
   ....: Cv[M[:, None], N] = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', B[M]/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]), B[N])
   ....: Yv[M] = np.einsum('i, ki->k', U[0, :, 1]/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]), B[M])
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop
```

Here's my test:

```
import numpy as np

# make fake data:
np.random.seed(5)

qi = np.random.rand(551)
N = np.random.randint(0,18,18)#np.arange(18)
M = np.random.randint(0,18,18)#np.arange(18)
I = np.arange(551)
Iq = np.random.rand(1, 551, 3)
U = np.random.rand(1, 551, 3)

B = np.zeros((18, 551))
C = np.zeros((18, 18))
Y = np.zeros((18))
Bv = np.zeros((18, 551))
Cv = np.zeros((18, 18))
Yv = np.zeros((18))

dmaxi = 1.

def B1(n, i):
    return np.pi * n * dmaxi * (-1)**(n+1) * np.sin(qi[i]*dmaxi) * ((np.pi*n)**2 - (qi[i]*dmaxi)**2)**(-1)

for n in N:
    B[n, :] = B1(n, I)

for m in M:
    for n in N:
        C[m, n] = np.dot((1/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]))*B[m, :], B[n, :])
    Y[m] = np.dot((1/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]))*U[0, :, 1], B[m, :])

Bv[N] = B1(N[:, None], I)
print "B correct?", np.allclose(Bv, B)

# np.einsum test case:
n, m = 2, 3
a = np.arange(n*m).reshape(n,m)*8 + 2
b = np.arange(n*m)[::-1].reshape(n,m)
c = np.empty((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        c[i,j] = np.dot(a[i],b[j])
cv = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', a, b)
print "einsum test successful?", np.allclose(c,cv)

Cv[M[:, None], N] = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',
        B[M]/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]),
        B[N])
print "C correct?", np.allclose(Cv, C)

Yv[M] = np.einsum('i, ki->k',
        U[0, :, 1]/np.square(qi*Iq[0, :, 2]),
        B[M])
print "Y correct?", np.allclose(Yv, Y)
```

output :D

```
B correct? True
einsum test successful? True
C correct? True
Y correct? True
```

Comment: wow.  very impressive speed increase. I didn't even think of reshaping N to be a column vector for that.  I tried to use the np.einsum previously but I wasn't able to get it to work so I thought maybe it wasn't applicable, but clearly I was wrong.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Please be sure to run your own code and mine, and make sure they work for your inputs.  I made some assumptions and hopefully it works but I don't want you not to double check!

Comment: Yes I had when I wrote my comment and accepted the answer.  I should've mentioned that. It gives all the same answers as before, just faster.